# Story about shadow people who measure a tree before a car accident

Tags: story-identification, foreshadowing

I've searched and searched and I can't find this story. I hope someone else knows what I'm on about.

Details:

- I am ~80% it's called "Shadow People".
- I am ~80% sure it's a short story in a collection or anthology (possibly a horror one). If it's not a short story, it's a novella.
- I am ~50% sure it was from a book published in the late 90s or early 00s.
- At the beginning the protagonist (I can't remember if it's a female or male, sorry) is watching out the window in their living room when they notice what they refer to as shadow people (described as if someone cut a human shape out of reality) measuring the distance from a tree to a point on the street and other sort of "public works" kind of actions. Sometime later (hours, days, weeks, unsure) a horrific and deadly car accident happens there, right along the trajectory that the shadow people were measuring previously.
- The shadow people notice the protagonist at some point and his/her life starts unraveling from there.
- I am about ~20% sure the end involves the protagonist sitting in an unfurnished room with all the lights on waiting for the shadow people to come for them.

I have scoured my books, the Internet, and even gone into some of those forums and sites that are dedicated to the paranormal where people talk about shadow people as real entities hoping to find this story, to no avail.

Thank you in advance for remembering what my tired old brain certainly cannot!

Comment: Are you sure this was a book? I've got vague memories of a similar story, but feel like it was a Twilight Zone ep or similar?

Comment: Positive it was a book. But I'm sure the premise isn't unique or even new.

Comment: Also: watched all of the original Twilight Zone on Netflix last year, definitely wasn't in there. But thank you!

Comment: @Miller86 There was a Twilight Zone episode entitled "The Shadow Man", but that was about a bogeyman who lived under a kid's bed. I remember that because I was somewhat disturbed by the ending as a kid myself. The wiki link is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shadow_Man

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1017035) lists a short story called "Shadow People" by Jan Carol Sabin in a 1990s anthology called "Ladies of Winter."  Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any details on the specific story itself, or even many on the anthology as a whole (it seems to be fairly small press and doesn't even have a Goodreads or Amazon page that I can detect), but the title and timeframe seem to fit.

Comment: Thanks! Checking this out now. Will let you know if this is the answer as soon as I find out. The anthology name "Ladies of Winter" doesn't sound familiar, but the author's name sort of does. EDIT: Pressed enter too soon.

Comment: For lack of a better answer, I'm marking this as the answer for now. *Future visitors: I have not actually confirmed this as the story, but it's the most likely candidate at this time.* Hopefully I can find my old book in storage and confirm.